# Client for Multipart form data to Rest WS with HTML as response

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jakarta-ee

I`m trying call a web service which returns an html page of that application ,
how to handle this in java client so that that html should be returned to my application UI.
I tried with  temporary redirect.
below is my code :

```
final MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()
            .field("msg", espXML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
            .field("obj", "", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
    multiPart.setMediaType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);


    return Response.temporaryRedirect(new URI("https://10.10.10.62:8080/abcde/1.2/wstest/"))
          //  .status(302)
            .entity(multiPart).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .build();
```

SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
    javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded was not found

Comment: Try reading data from the input stream, and write those data to the output stream of the response. No need to redirect the request. But your problem seem to be on the web-service side. 500 error usually means a bug in the server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to annotate the `MediaType` of your `Response` like:

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public InputStream yourFormMethod(...) {
   // your processing with your MultiPart
   File f = getHtmlFile();
   return new FileInputStream(f);
}
```

or

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public String yourFormMethod(...) {
   // your processing with your MultiPart
   String yourHtml = "<head>...</head>";
   return yourHtml;
}
```

And make sure you use the `JAX-RS` `@Produces` not the `CDI` one.